# APEX Access to Default Case Owner and Automated Case User

Tags: apex

Is the user/queue set as the Default Case Owner and Automated Case User accessible via Apex?

I'm creating a visualforce extension where I want to assign either the Default Case Owner or the Automated Case User as the Case OwnerID when a Query for a Queue fails.

I don't want to use the default Case Owner by just inserting the case since I cannot depend on Case Assignment rules properly assigning the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think they are available from the API as they are part of "settings".

If you do not (or do not want to) use assignment rules then you might want to consider using Custom Settings to hold Default Case Owner, etc values for you. You can easily refer these from within your code without hard-coding.

Comment: feel free to remove your signature. Users can see who wrote the post and the history by clicking on your badge.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I just hate to provide one more place to defined a default when Salesforce already makes you do it! Thanks