# What API to use to retrieve EmailToCase settings in Apex Class?

Tags: apex, email2case

Metadata API has mention of Settings, CaseSettings & EmailTocaseSettings but is that the way to go? Can it be used in Apex code to get/set 'default case owner', 'defaultCaseUser' etc?

May be it's not possible via Apex directly.
[APEX Access to Default Case Owner and Automated Case User](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/apex-access-to-default-case-owner-and-automated-case-user)

Comment: Email2Case - no idea. We2Case - [`Organization`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) object looks promising. Why do you need these? I doubt we'd be able to set them via Metadata API anyway, with all the hassle of confirming the email address is accessible...

Comment: @eyescream readonly information would have done. I need it because SOW has it. I am trying something, will update here if that works.